# Can Google Docs issue HTTP notifications when content changes?

Tags: push, doc, notify

I'm looking for a POST to a URL I provide when, say a doc in a certain folder is created, changed or deleted. I understand there's an RSS type feed I can poll and check manually but I'm wondering if there's a smarter push mechanism available.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) . Despite a funny name its a serious protocol to notify about content updates. It's used by [Google](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/HubbubAtGoogle) and a number of other [companies](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/Companies)